# NoSuchMethodException: for sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.addAppURL(java.net.URL) in jdk1.8.0

Tags: java, python, java-8

I am facing a very strange problem in my code. I was using below code to download my jar files. This was working properly in JAVA-5 and JAVA-6.

```
def AddJarToClassloader(self,u):
    #sysloader = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
    sysloader = java.net.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
    sysclass = sysloader.getClass()
    print 'All Methods:  ' + str(sysclass.getDeclaredMethods())
    method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addAppURL", [java.net.URL])
    print 'All method= ' + str(method)
    method.setAccessible(1)
    jar_a = java.net.URL(u)
    b = method.invoke(sysloader, [jar_a])
    return sysloader
```

But, recently we have updated all of our Linux machines into Java 8. Now, this code is no longer working. I am getting following error in the log file. Can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Error Log for JAVA-8:

```
[java] All Methods:  array(java.lang.reflect.Method, [public java.lang.Class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, private void sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.appendToClassPathForInstrumentation(java.lang.String), private static java.security.AccessControlContext sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.getContext(java.io.File[]) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, protected java.security.PermissionCollection sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.getPermissions(java.security.CodeSource), public static java.lang.ClassLoader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.getAppClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader) throws java.io.IOException])
 [java] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.addAppURL(java.net.URL)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:175)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:355)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:414)
 [java]     at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:418)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in Java 8 method `addAppURL` was removed from `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` class. But you can try to use method `java.net.URLClassLoader#addURL`, because `URLClassLoader` is the parent of `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`.

So try to change line

```
method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addAppURL", [java.net.URL])
```

with line

```
method = sysclass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("addURL", [java.net.URL])
```

Comment: …to be broken in Java 9 and newer.

Comment: @Holger, this is useful addition, and I will update my answer when I find smart solution for Java 9 and higher. By the way, in [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html) for Java 9 Oracle says _"Note that Java SE and the JDK do not provide an API for applications or libraries to dynamically augment the class path at run-time"_.

Comment: Well, actually, the Instrumentation API offers a standardized way of adding entries to the class path, however, this is not a mandatory feature. Besides that, dynamically augmenting the class path indeed never was supported officially.